# Facing error during grind framework installation in mac os

Tags: node.js, frontend, backend

I am new to grind framework. I follow the steps describe in the below url for the installation.

https://grind.rocks/docs/0.7/guides/installation

Installation is successfully completed and while i try to run the project with the following command it gives me the fatal error which is describe in the below.

Command :

> $ bin/cli watch

Error :

```
Mac-iMac-1s-iMac:project-name Mac-imac-1$ bin/cli watch
Watching app,config
Failed to start Error: Plugin 0 specified in "/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-preset-grind/index.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-preset-grind/index.js")
at Plugin.init (/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin.js:131:13)
at Function.normalisePlugin (/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:152:12)
at /Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.normalisePlugins (/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
at /Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:265:14
at /Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:323:22
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/Mac-imac-1/Desktop/demoes/project-name/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem so as per my opinion you have to change the package version as mentioned below.

In package.json file find the section “devDependencies” in that  you can see "babel-preset-grind": "^0.8.0-beta.1". We need to remove beta version of package.

> "babel-preset-grind": "^0.8.0-beta.1" to "babel-preset-grind": "0.7.0"

Then need to execute below command from your terminal.

```
$ npm install
$bin/cli watch
```